# Linked Module Dependencies are not resolved

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, npm-link

I am facing an issue related to `npm link`

This is the case of publishing modules locally and using them in other angular apps.  I have 2 apps

**1) app-core (published locally) 

2) app-main**

`app-core` contains following dependencies (installed via npm):

> core 
>   rxjs 
>   zone 
>   ng2-cache // Pay attention to this! 
>   etc...

---

`app-main` contains following dependencies (installed via npm):

> core 
>   rxjs 
>   http 
>   etc...

---

I am linking **app-core** module to local npm using (sym link)

```
npm link
```

*linked this module globally*

---

Now I am using **app-core** inside my **app-main** using

```
npm link app-core
```

Things are good as of now, when i build my **app-main** it's showing me following errors:

```
ERROR in ../app-core/dist/core/services/remote.service.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng2-cache/ng2-cache' in 'C:\Dhaval\app-core\dist\core\services'
 @ ../app-core/dist/core/services/remote.service.js 14:18-48
 @ ../app-core/dist/upoint.core.js
 @ ./src/shared/shared.module.ts
 @ ./src/app-features/app-features.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

**Explanation:**
***ng2-cache** was the dependency injected inside the **app-core** and **ng2-cache** itself is a kind of a custom module, so it became nesting now as i am using a Custom module (ng2-cache) inside another module app-core (my own) and this **app-core** i am using inside **app-main**.*

This is the case that's bothering me, my app-main module isn't getting that ng2-cache module resolve within. What should i do?

Appreciate your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

It won't install dependencies of dependencies when using a linked project. Only when the project is published and then installed conventionally.

You should make a dependency on the same library in app-main